# How can I stop an image element from taking 100% width?

Tags: html, css, sass

This seems simple but nothing I'm trying works...I have an image that is assigned a class. The image has a certain width, but the class assigned to the image takes up 100% of the parent div's width, no matter what I do.

**html:**

```
<div class="parent">
  <%= image_tag("picture.png"), class:"image" %>
</div>
```

**css with sass:**

```
.parent {
  width 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  .image {
    position: absolute;
    height: 80%;
    max-height: 1000px;
  }
}
```

Using various answers I've found around the web, I've tried different combinations of giving `.image` `width: auto`, `display:inline` and `display:inline-block`, but no matter what I do, `.image` refuses to budge from 100%. How can I make `.image` only as wide as the image it contains??

Comment: This is not a Sass or Haml problem, only provide the compiled CSS/HTML.

Comment: To me it seems like the code works exactly as you want. http://jsfiddle.net/svgaa0tp/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out I have to add the class to the image itself, not the erb string:

```
<div class="parent">
  <%= image_tag ("picture.png", class:"image") %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="path" class="image" width="20%" />
</div>
```